# Disable CORS for 2 paths

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-cors-headers

I'm using django-cors-header for CORS, I want to disable CORS (allow all) for 2 routes

```
(ex: /api/test1/, /api/test2)
```

other route is still enable CORS (only allow for CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST host

Are there any way to do that ?

I've tried to set CORS_URLS_REGEX but then all route cannot be accessed

```
CORS_URLS_REGEX = r'^(?!(/api/test1/|/api/test2/).*'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this regex. I think it can help:
`^(?!(/?api/test1/?$|/?api/test2/?$)).*`

I've checked this regex pattern on the website regex101 and it was okay.